# is/are - in given scenario

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural

My biggest fear **is** cockroaches and spiders.

My biggest fears **are** cockroaches and spiders.

My biggest fear **are** cockroaches and spiders.

Are all these sentences grammatically correct? If not which are incorrect? If the last one is incorrect, why?

Comment: The first two are idiomatic; the last is not. I wouldn't venture to say whether any of them are ungrammatical.

Comment: Do you mean cockroaches and spiders together somehow as one big fear? Or do you mean that your two biggest fears are c's and s's?

Comment: You really can't use the first sentence because it's not idiomatic. That is, "cockroaches and spiders" are not one idiomatic unit, unlike say "wine and cheese".

Answer (score 1):

The first two are okay; the third is not. And for that matter, "Cockroaches and spiders *are* my biggest fear" would also be okay. **Why?**

First, because the number of the verb should agree with the subject. If the subject is singular, the verb is *is*; if it's plural it's *are*.

Second, because multiple things can make up one entity.

> My favorite couple is Lucy & Ricky.

You could say that your biggest fear "is" cockroaches and spiders. By this you mean that you count them together as one "fear." Or your could say that they are "fears," two of them. Either way, the verb should agree with the subject. So any of these beginnings would be wrong:

> My biggest fear are...
> My biggest fears is...
> Cockroaches and spiders is...

... But they are wrong because of subject/verb agreement, not because of whether two things "count" as one.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it's idiomatic that cockroaches and spiders make up one logical entity.

Comment: Logical? Maybe, maybe not (maybe someone is afraid of "all creepy-crawlies," without regard to 6 vs 8 legs). But this question isn't so much about which words as about the grammar. (And certainly, some combinations are often treated as one thing—mac and cheese, peanut butter and jelly, Laurel and Hardy...)

Comment: My point is that nobody thinks of "cockroaches and spiders" together as one unit. The grammar only works if C&S are one unit, like PB&J. "My favorite food is mac and cheese."

Comment: @FeliniusRex Hm, it seems reasonable enough to me. True, it's not an existing collocation like PB&J (or even "Lions and tigers and bears"), but I don't know that a phobia of cockroaches and spiders needs to be parsed as two distinct phobias (such fears are often illogical anyway, right?). What if I fear eels and snakes—it's a grouping that doesn't make much taxonomic sense, but I don't think it's unreasonable to say "My greatest **fear is** eels and snakes."